# How to switch iFrame on iOS automation @PoornimaSuraj

Tags: ios, web, mobile, automation, appium

I am getting error on switching to iFrame on iOS Automation but it is working fine on Android.
Error:blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Tried the fetching url and open but the page is blank, and also tried to switch to native but it is not working